# Menu CSS fechando ao clicar nos itens de dentro

Tags: css, menu

Fiz o seguinte menu em *css* e a abertura/fechamneto está funcionando normal, porém quando eu clico em algum item do submenu, o menu fecha antes de redirecionar.

Teria alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

```css
#menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 100px;
}

.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  color: #969696;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

.open-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../../img/select-arrow-down.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.open-button:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
 }

.open-button:focus + ul {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 40px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #ccc;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <div class="item">
      <span class="open-button" tabindex="0">Menu</span>

    <ul>
         <li>
           <a href="{{ route('cliente-conta') }}">Meus dados</a>
         </li>

         <li>
           <a href="{{ route('pedidos') }}">Meus pedidos</a>
         </li>

         <li>
           <a href="{{ route('cliente-logout') }}">Sair</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Já tentou usando `preventDefault() ` ou `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: Não quero usar nada de JS para isso, queria deixar esse menu 100% CSS

Comment: Fiz um modelo para vc ver na minha resposta só com CSS, mas tive em vez de um `span` eu usei um `input checkbox`, e em vez de `:focus` usei `:checked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego vc não consegue manter o menu aberto porque está usando a pseudo class `:focus` para abrir o Menu, então quando vc troca o `:focus` (clicando no link) o menu `.open-button:focus` perde o foco e fecha o Menu. *Fiz um exemplo que pode te servi. Não fiz todo o CSS do menu que abre pq acho que não é o objetivo aqui.*

Para resolver seu problema fiz o Menu usando um `checkbox`, quanto ele está checkado abre o menu, e quando não ele fecha o menu com `display:block/none` e a estilização vc faz usando a pseudo classe `:checked`

Veja abaixo um modelo simples usando um pseudo elemento `::after` para fazer um ícone ao abrir e fechar *(tudo bem simples, mas vc pode usar imagens no `content:''` se quiser)*

```css
.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  color: #969696;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  color: #969696;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

ul {
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
}
input:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
input + label::after {
    content: " +";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input:checked + label::after {
    content: " -";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
    <label class="item" for="menu">Menu</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('cliente-conta') }}">Meus dados</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('pedidos') }}">Meus pedidos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('cliente-logout') }}">Sair</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**OBS:** Precisei mexer um pouco na estrutura das tags no HTML, mas nada de mais, na verdade ficou até mais simples de entender.

Comment: Não tem como fazer o menu fechar (desmarcar checkbox) ao clicar fora dele, apenas com css né?

Comment: Diego só com CSS não da, pq como é um Checkbox vc teria que tira o "checked" dele, para isso só com JS ou jQueri. Não é nada complicado, se vc postar esse código em 5 min alguém te responde com um Script que tira o checked do input quando clicar fora. E mesmo que eu de display:none nele ele vai continuar com o "checked" ai vc vai precisar clicar 2x nele para abrir de novo, vai ficar parecendo um bug. Acredito que só com CSS não da. Vc pode até fazer outra pergunta sobre isso tb, as vezes alguém aparece com a solução